# PL/SQL Oracle Package error

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, package, procedure

The issue I am having is with the package body, I have tried to change my code in the select statement for the second procedure several times and I have not been able to figure this out.

Does anyone have any insight? All my code and error is below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE check_emp_pkg IS
    g_max_length_of_service CONSTANT NUMBER := 100;

PROCEDURE chk_hiredate
    (p_date IN employees.hire_date%TYPE);

PROCEDURE chk_dept_mgr
    (p_empid IN employees.employee_id%TYPE
     , p_mgr IN employees.manager_id%TYPE);

END check_emp_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY check_emp_pkg IS

PROCEDURE chk_hiredate
    (p_date IN employees.hire_date%TYPE) 
IS BEGIN

  IF MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, p_date) > g_max_length_of_service * 12 THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20200, 'Invalid Hiredate');
 END IF;
END chk_hiredate;

PROCEDURE chk_dept_mgr
(p_empid IN employees.employee_id%TYPE, p_mgr IN employees.manager_id%TYPE) IS BEGIN
  IF SELECT employee_id, manager_id INTO p_empid, p_mgr
   FROM employees
    WHERE manager_id = p_mgr THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SUCCESS');
  ELSE NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA FOUND');
 END IF;
 END chk_dept_mgr;

END check_emp_pkg;
/
```

> Error at line 15: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CHECK_EMP_PKG"
>   when expecting one of the following:    ;
>
> 1. CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY check_emp_pkg IS
> 2. PROCEDURE chk_hiredate
> 3. (p_date IN employees.hire_date%TYPE) IS BEGIN

Comment: Your package body syntax is really messed-up.  You cannot do, "IF SELECT.."  you need to do a select into, then check any condition.  Recommend to read some pl/sql tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample table and illustrated how to use your procedure. A lot of mistakes in your coding.

1.) you are using     p_empid     as an input variable, you cant use it to store a value from the select clause again.
Solution: Use another variable to assign the value .

2.) Using select in the IF clause .
Solution : Use     Select into    , into a variable and use that to validate in your if statement.

3.) Make better use of NO_DATA_FOUND  as an Exception.

Here is a sample, have created an employee table with just 2 fields for the example

```
create table employees (employee_id int, manager_id int);
INSERT INTO employees (employee_id,manager_id) values (123,456);

SQL> SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES;

EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID
----------- ----------
        123        456

SQL>

SQL>     create or replace  PROCEDURE chk_dept_mgr
  2       (p_empid IN employees.employee_id%TYPE, p_mgr IN employees.manager_id%TYPE) IS
  3       l_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE:=p_empid ;
  4       l_mgr employees.manager_id%TYPE:=p_mgr;
  5       emp_count int;
  6       BEGIN
  7
  8         SELECT count(1) into emp_count
  9          FROM employees where manager_id=l_mgr ;
 10          IF (emp_count>0)
 11           THEN
 12          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SUCCESS');
 13          ELSE
 14          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO employee found');
 15         END IF;
 16        END chk_dept_mgr;
 17
 18       /

Procedure created.

SQL>  exec chk_dept_mgr(123,456);
SUCCESS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>  exec chk_dept_mgr(123,457);
NO employee found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS HOW MY PACKAGE BODY IS SUPPOSE TO LOOK. THANK YOU FOR THE HELP.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY check_emp_pkg IS
PROCEDURE chk_hiredate
    (p_date IN employees.hire_date%TYPE) 
IS 
  g_max_length_of_service CONSTANT NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
  IF MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, p_date) > g_max_length_of_service * 12 THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20200, 'Invalid Hiredate');
 END IF;
END chk_hiredate;
PROCEDURE chk_dept_mgr
(p_empid IN employees.employee_id%TYPE, p_mgr IN employees.manager_id%TYPE) IS 
v_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE;
v_mgr   employees.manager_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT employee_id, manager_id INTO v_empid, v_mgr
   FROM employees
   WHERE employee_id = p_empid;
  IF p_mgr = v_mgr THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SUCCESS');
   ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE NUMBERS ENTERED DO NOT MATCH AN EMPLOYEE AND MANAGER COMBINATION');
 END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA FOUND');
 END chk_dept_mgr;
END check_emp_pkg;
```